# Android using getActivity()

Tags: android-fragments

I have a general question for Android "best practices".

Let's take a fragment for example, where i need to have access to the activity **multiple times**.

I can do the following:

1- Keep calling getActivity()

2- Override the onAttach() method of the fragment, save the Acitivty as a variable once and keep using it throughout the fragment, like so:

```
private Activity activity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.activity = (Activity) context;
}
```

Is there any difference between both methods? which is considered better for performance/memory/etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While watching a random Android talk i got an amazing answer to my questions by Jake Wharton.

The answer is NOT to call getActivity() multiple times. Just save the activity as a field for reuse.

Link for the talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6zKBZcg5fk